# FOSUserBundle: trying to override layout.html.twig

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Im trying to override the layout.html.twig of FOSUserBundle.

So I have my new layout.html.twig at `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig` but it is not used..

I have tried also at `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig` but it is not used either..

I have also cleared my cache

The original one is at: `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Resources/views`

These are the instructions I followed: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md

Comment: This is correct. Have you tried deleting your cache folders manually?

Comment: @Fred thanks, but doesn't work

Comment: Just a quick try: Copy the `Security/login.html.twig` into `app/Resources/FOSUserbundle/views/Security` and see if the login screen makes use of your new layout.html.twig.

Comment: Okay, can you post the code of your layout.html.twig?

Comment: @Fred Im using the same template as in the documentation: `{% extends 'AcmeDemoBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Acme Demo Application{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}`